# Xcode 7 iOS 9 UITableViewCell Separator Inset issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode7, ios9

This is not a question, rather a solution to the problem I faced.

In Xcode 7, when the application is run on iOS 9 on iPad devices, the `UITableViewCell` leaves some margin onto the left side of the `UITableView`. And rotating the device to the landscape would increase the margins.

The solution I found is:

Setting `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth` to `NO`.

```
self.tbl_Name.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
```

This property is only available in iOS 9. So, you will have to put a condition to check the iOS version, else it will crash.

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_1)
{
    self.tbl_Name.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
}
```

Comment: [Have a same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537196/ios-9-uitableview-separators-significant-left-margin)

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly for me especially on iPad with iOS 9.

Comment: I just encountered a serious problem with this answer, it uses version `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_1`, it needs to use `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_4` instead, otherwise it will crash the app running iOS8.2 and iOS8.3 and IOS8.4

Comment: I use to get my system version with `float version =  [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];` so you can easily compare then with `if (version >= 9.0)` (and so prevent potential crash due to further updates of the same iOS version)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845075/ios-9-uitableview-cells-text-label-not-the-full-width-of-the-uitableview for a slightly better approach , detecting functionality rather than iOS9 version number

Answer (score 39):

**iOS 9 and above:**

This is because of a new feature called readable content guides. It provides margins that are suitable for reading. So, on iPhone and portrait iPad they are very small margins. But in the landscape, iPad they are bigger. In iOS 9, `UITableViewCell` margins default to following the readable content guide.

If you want to stop that, just set the tableView's `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth` to `NO/false`.

**Source:** https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5496

Comment: Very nice answer! Regret that it is not yet documented. That question occurred while I was preparing [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537196/ios-9-uitableview-separators-insets-significant-left-margin/)

Answer (score 13):

**Up to iOS 9**

***In viewDidLoad***

Objective-C

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Required for iOS 9
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] >= 9.0) {
        self.testTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
    }
}
```

Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        tableViewDiet.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
    }
}
```

***In TableViewDelegate methods add following code:***

Objective-C

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Remove seperator inset
    if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setSeparatorInset:")) {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:")) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. That is why I had to look for some other approach.

Comment: This is not working with iOS 9. Have you tested it with iOS 9 and Xcode 7 with properly set command line tools in the preferences?

Comment: If you are using swift you should be using `if #available(iOS 9.0, *)` condition check.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is helpful.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
      myTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`readableContentGuide` is a layout guide that is already added to every `UIView`.

This is to ensure the user doesn't have to turn his head to read the content.

If you want to follow the readable content guide, then do the following:

```
let baseSection = UIView()

contentView.addSubview(baseSection)

baseSection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: 4, right: 0)

baseSection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: insets.left).isActive = true
baseSection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -insets.right).isActive = true
baseSection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: insets.top).isActive = true
baseSection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -insets.bottom).isActive = true
```

Note: In the code above the bottom and top anchors use the contentView instead of the `readableContentGuide` so that the content vertical margins change based on the `tableView.rowHeight`.