# iOS 9 UITableView separators insets (significant left margin)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, xcode7, ios9

I have a problem with separators between `UITableViewCell`s in `UITableView` on `iOS 9`. They have the significant left margin. I already have code for removing spacing introduced by `iOS 8` but it doesn't work with `iOS 9`. It looks like they added something else. I suppose it might be connected with [layoutMarginsGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMarginsGuide) but I haven't figured it out yet. Does anyone had a similar problem and found out the solution?

Comment: Apple Developer Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20017

Comment: This answer may help others with the same issues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38206546/1137246

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Okay, [I have found out the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31536736/3151066). The only thing required for that is to set on the presenting instance of `UITableView` that flag `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth`

```
myTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
```

I wanted to find some reference in the documentation but it looks like it is not ready yet, [only mentioned on diff page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/modules/UIKit.html).

As the flag was introduced in iOS 9 for the backward compatibility you should add a check before trying to set it:

```
if([myTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setCellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth:)])
{
    myTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
}
```

For `Swift 2.0` you can use `#available` to check iOS version.

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    myTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
}
```

Moreover you need to compile it with `Xcode 7` or above.

**EDIT**

Please keep in mind that this is the only required fix if your separators looked "fine" up to iOS 8, otherwise you need to change a bit more. You can find info how to do this already on SO.

Comment: Thanks for that! is there any option to turn this feature off for the whole app or do I have to manually Update all TableViewController properties?

Comment: Have you considered creating a base class for tableview (set it there) and use it wherever possible? Moreover I would look if it can be set by appearance.

Comment: yes this is what I'm doing right now (base class approach) I was just wondering if there would be some kind of "global switch" to shut this off completely. I tried the appearance stuff but this doesn't work with `[[UITableView appearance] setCellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth:NO];`

Comment: Maybe that could be a next SO question how (if possible) to set it globally :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect on iOS 9.1.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen has it worked for you for previous versions?

Comment: @JulianKról I haven't tried with any earlier version yet.

Comment: So this is only the addition you need if your separators where fine on iOS 8. This is what changed between iOS 8 and 9. Find how to fix it on iOS 8 (it is already on SO) and add this and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for this! Any idea why, on iPad, this code makes a full width separator on empty cells, but when data is added to a cell there are a few pixels on the left side where the separator is missing? I found a patch/fix for this but just wondering if you may know more.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to do it in interface builder. The default separator inset is `Automatic`. Change it to `custom` by selecting the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: The "Seperator Inset" is Automatic as default and do not show Left/Right unti it is changed to Custom.

Answer (score 18):

Swift 2.2 iOS 9.3

In viewDidLoad

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

In UITableViewDelegates

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setSeparatorInset:")){
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
    if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
    if cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:")){
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3.0 / 4.0**

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.separatorInset)) {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.layoutMargins)) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Perfect Solution upto iOS 9**

***In viewDidLoad***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Required for iOS 9
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] >= 9.0) {
        self.testTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
    }
}
```

***In TableViewDelegate methods add following code:***

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, if you copy code from the other answer on SO it would be nice if you mention the original author with a link to its answer (that would be fair). Secondly instead of checking iOS version you can check whether object responds to selector.

Comment: @JulianKról You are right about respond to selector its an alternative. And this is my solution I have created a demo project for this too and working properly on all iOS versions. It would really feel great if you appreciate.

Comment: yeah but the second part of the code I already seen on the SO with same comments etc. Moreover making every thing bold and italic also do not improves its readability :) Further, the question is explicit about iOS 9 assuming that up to iOS 8 everything was already done (that counts to the second part of your answer). I appreciate yours involvement but I'm giving you my feedback

Comment: Yeah that was actually I was using till iOS 8. But for iOS 9 besides this code one must set self.testTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO . So for the proper answer I have mentioned the complete code.

Comment: what about link to the original answer on SO ? you didn't say anything about that :)

Comment: @JulianKról Ok noted. Will keep this in mind for future. Thnks.

Answer (score 5):

This worked perfectly for me in   iOS 9.

For **OBJ-C**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  { 
        if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
        {
            [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

        if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
        {
            [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }

        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
        {
            [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }
         return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on different answers here, I am able to remove the gap from separator with these lines of codes in Swift:

```
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

But still I am having this small gap before the text:

[image]

Comment: As a workaround, I have just put constraint of `-14` for `UITableView` instead of using above codes to align the table manually.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Until I moved `setCellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth` BEFORE `setLayoutMargins` (still needed for iOS 8):

```
if([_tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setCellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth:)]) {
  _tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
}

if ([_tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
  _tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Comment: this is what I needed! The order matters. For me, I noticed that the order mattered for iPad table views in landscape. Once rotated it was fixed, but the first sight of the table was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Remove seperator inset

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

}
```

Comment: Not in my case. This was working fine up to the version 8 of iOS. Something else seems to be required for iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 8 and 9

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([UITableView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) [[UITableViewCell appearance] setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    if ([UITableView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) [[UITableViewCell appearance] setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for Swift 3.0/iOS 10 in XCode 8.2.1.

I have created a subclass for UITableview which works for IB and programmatically create tableviews.

```
import UIKit

class EXCSuperTV: UITableView
{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {}
}

class EXCNoFooter: EXCSuperTV
{
    override func setupView()
    {
        super.setupView()
        //tableFooterView = UIView.Zero()
    }
}


class EXCMainTV: EXCNoFooter
{
    override func setupView()
    {
        super.setupView()
        separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```