# iOS 9 UITableView cell's text label not the full width of the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Since updating to iOS 9, table view cell's in iPad landscape no longer stretch the full width of the table in my unit tests.

My test is a simple table that takes a snapshot at the end.

```
- (void)testTableSize{
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,viewController.view.bounds.size.width, viewController.view.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;

    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [viewController.view addSubview:tableView];

    ASCSnapshotVerifyViewiPad([viewController view]);
}
```

The cells are very simple for this example

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];   // Demo purpose
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // Demo purpose
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", (int)indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

but my cell is drawn with a big margin on the left and right. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: You need `AutoLayout`. Please add screenshot of your `storyboard`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using AutoLayout. The table is create in a Unit Test with initWithFrame.

Comment: @Alan R U using custom UITableViewCell with xib?

Comment: @Alan R U trying autoresize your cell.?

Comment: No custom cell used.

Comment: try to add autoresizing. cell created has its xib or not?

Comment: No xib and cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth didn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90900/discussion-between-jay-raparka-and-alan).

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: what is the blue color view is ?

Comment: Great question, thanks for posting and enduring what passes for "scrutiny" here on SO in comments.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When I tested my App with iOS9, I noticed huge margins, on some UITableViews, both left and right. After a bit of investigation, I found the following new method:

```
// iOS9
if([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setCellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth:)]) {
    self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
}
```

When the above code is called, after instantiating your UITableView, it should remove them.

Paste this code after you set your tableView delegate.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps, but what does "a bit of investigation" mean? Did you take this advice from somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dan - yes, a bit of self-education and research. Discovered this shortly after iOS9 emerged.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just not seeing anything about this being a new thing in iOS 9. I mean, reading the API and trying stuff out is a great, but I'm guessing you read something somewhere.

Comment: Yes I did. Not totally sure where. It was a while ago. All I can say is, this whole margin issue came about as a result of profiling my Apps with iOS9. I discovered setting the above property = NO handled my problem. So, I shared it.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Answer (score -1):

hope this help you

```
    //    MARK: - TableView Delegates And Datasource Method -

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // IOS 7
    if(self.respondsToSelector(Selector("setSeparatorInset:"))){
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
    // OTHER
    if(self.respondsToSelector(Selector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:"))){
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }
    }

    // iOS 8
    if(self.respondsToSelector(Selector("setLayoutMargins:"))){
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
    }
    // iOS 9
    if (self.respondsToSelector("setCellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth:")){
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            self.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
        }
    }
}
```