# UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine width changing when iPad is rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

I wrote the following code:

```
 tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Comment: can u added the screen shot

Comment: try in real device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536187/xcode-7-ios-9-uitableviewcell-separator-inset-issue

Comment: tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
 thanks @PKT

Answer (score 0):

```
    // iOS 7
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .SingleLine
    UITableView.appearance().separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    UITableViewCell.appearance().separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    // iOS 8
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *)
    {
        UITableView.appearance().layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        UITableViewCell.appearance().layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        UITableViewCell.appearance().preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }

    // iOS 9
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *)
    {
        UITableView.appearance().cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
    }
```