# UITableViewCell separator insets don't work when table.width is much greater than view.width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, separator, insets

UITableViewCell separator insets don't work when table.width is much greater than view.width on iOS 10, I haven't try it on the device which iOS version is less then iOS 10.

[image]

[code is here on gist](https://gist.github.com/adin283/cd2b8216dc81d49160901168fa14dc78)

Comment: the separator line if full, when tableview.width=600,but if the width is greater than 700,the separator shows the insets on the left and right sides. i tried it on the iPhone5S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can solve this problem.

First one you can add a separator line view in cell content view.

```
 UIView* line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableview.frame.size.width, 3)];      
 line.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[cell.contentView addSubview:line];
```

The second one is apple provided one and pretty easy also just add this line of code where u declare your tableview

```
yourTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add separator in your `UITableView` using the below code

```
 UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 3)];/// change size as you need.       
 separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];// you can also put image here
 [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

and remove the default separator of your `UITableView`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thx. I know custom separator line work well. But I want to know why system separator line have insets.

Answer (score 1):

```
_tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
```

it works above.

refer to

[iOS 9 UITableView separators insets (significant left margin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537196/ios-9-uitableview-separators-insets-significant-left-margin)

[Xcode 7 iOS 9 UITableViewCell Separator Inset issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536187/xcode-7-ios-9-uitableviewcell-separator-inset-issue/31536736#31536736)